# Can anyone please recommend any good Load Testing software?

Tags: load-testing

Can anyone please recommend any good Load Testing software? I have a website which updates scores every minute via ajax calls and need a load testing software which supports ajax calls (javascript) too!

Comment: Exactly what do you want to test. "Load testing" is really vague.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ab` from the apache webserver to test load via http

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there are no tools which realistically support ajax testing (but interested to hear if anyone knows different). There are lots which *claim* to - but in practice they tend to fall into 2 camps - those which merely generate HTTP calls to an Ajax service, and ones which attempt to automate a browser (and usually fail, are hard to script if its possible at all, and provide very little realistic performance metrics).

Generating HTTP traffic and measuring performance is trivial though. There are lots of tools available, e.g. [http::recorder + www::mechanize](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/04/recorder.html) (perl), and lots more listed [here](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard load testing tools to do this, you just need to add the URLs to your back-end services to the list of URLs for the application to hit from time to time along with your front-end pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) if it's a web based aplication. If not, please add more details about what you want to test.

> Apache JMeter  is open source software, a 100% pure Java desktop application designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebLOAD from http://www.radview.com/, it works well with Ajax, and uses JavaScript as the scripting language

Answer (score 0):

"AFAIK, there are no tools which realistically support ajax testing (but interested to hear if anyone knows different). There are lots which claim to - but in practice they tend to fall into 2 camps - those which merely generate HTTP calls to an Ajax service, and ones which attempt to automate a browser (and usually fail, are hard to script if its possible at all, and provide very little realistic performance metrics)."

See HP TruClient in LoadRunner for a solution which has full AJAX support.   However, given the definition of a business process which simply updates every minute it should be easy to emulate this traffic with a straight HTTP virtual user from any number of commercial or open source tools and a timer structure which holds for a period of time before updating.

If this update in the client is running concurrent with other actions, i.e. frame 1 is user input and frame 2 is an AJAX solution constantly updating, then you do have  a bit more of a mechanical challenge on the tool front.    You can go either the full AJAX route or decouple the updating content from the user interaction in two scripts.    Something to keep in mind that when you do find a client type which is fully AJAX compliant you also inherit the weight of a full browser, the javascript engine and the the majority of the rendering engine.  That weight is translated to use of memory and use of CPU, so you will not get as many virtual users per host.